# What type of S3 IAM action do I need to copy a file?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-iam

I'm able to get an object using `get_object` and `put_object` on my bucket, but can't execute `copy_object`. Currently using Python's Boto3. I see my IAM actions allow `get*` and `put` but what else do I need?

Error: `An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the CopyObject operation: Access Denied`

```
copy_source = {
    'Bucket': 'mybucket',
    'Key': 's3/B.csv'
}
response = client.copy_object(Bucket=bucket, CopySource=copy_source, Key='test/copied.csv')
```

Comment: "can't execute copy_object" - edit your question to include any errors/messages you're getting.  As well as the code that's causing it.

Comment: DO you have IAM privileges in both source and destination buckets?

Comment: Yes, I've tried this with the source and destination buckets being the same bucket and getting this error

Comment: At a guess, HeadObject. Try with Head* and maybe List*.

Comment: If you are NOT the bucket owner, please check your bucket policy. Even better, post the bucket policy up here ; as long as you mask all unique id, there is nothing to worry about bucket policy secrecy.

Answer (score 0):

This is the basic bucket policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "DaveBucketAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::AccountB-ID:user/Dave"
            },
            "Action":   ["s3:ListObject", "s3:PutObject","s3:GetObject"],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/"]
        }
    ]
}
```

You can always use [Policy simulator](https://policysim.aws.amazon.com/) to checkout user access. You can also use the deduction method, i.e. use `"Action" : "s3:*"` to open up all access first to make sure nothing wrong with your user, then close up the access one by one.